# Possible to skip plotly add_markers() line when no data applies?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a Shiny app that dynamically displays a plot based on a user's input query. For a simple example, I  will explain using the `mtcars` dataset. My problem is that for some datasets, there exists no values where `mtcars$mpg > 19 & mtcars$mpg < 25`. How can I modify this code so that it will apply to all possible datasets? (i.e. where all `mtcars$mpg < 18` or all `mtcars$mpg > 19 & < 25` or  all `mtcars$mpg > 26`)

I wish there was some kind of parameter I could pass to `add_markers()` like `necessary = FALSE` where it could skip that line if none of the data applies. Right now I am getting the error:

> Error: Must supply `x` and `y` attributes

How can I circumvent this?

```
 p <- plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = 'markers') %>%
      add_markers(x = which(mtcars$mpg < 18), y = mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg < 18], marker = list(color = 'black', symbol = 'cross')) %>%
      add_markers(x = which(mtcars$mpg > 19 & mtcars$mpg < 25), y = mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg > 19 & mtcars$mpg <25], marker = list(color = 'orange', symbol = 'square')) %>%
      add_markers(x = which(mtcars$mpg > 26), y = mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg > 26], marker = list(color = 'red', symbol = 'circle'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a more elegant solution, but you could store the data for your markers in a list, and loop over that list as follows:

```
subsets  = list(list(indices = mtcars$mpg < 18,color='black', symbol='cross'),
                list(indices = mtcars$mpg > 19 & mtcars$mpg < 25,color = 'orange', symbol = 'square'),
                list(indices = mtcars$mpg > 26,color = 'red', symbol = 'circle'))

p <- plot_ly(type = "scatter", mode = 'markers')
for(i in 1:length(subsets))
{
  z = subsets[[i]]
  if(sum(z$indices)>0) p %<>% add_markers(x = which(z$indices), y = mtcars$mpg[z$indices], marker = list(color = z$color, symbol = z$symbol)) 
}
```

This will prevent the error, even when run with `mtcars = head(mtcars,10)` where there is no data for one of the three groups.